# Squid DNS FAIL when trying to connect to localhost

Tags: http, proxy, localhost, squid

I'm running a local http server and local squid instance. A local http client opens a socket connecting to the squid instance, which seems to work. I then try to tunnel to the local http server by issuing the following http request:

```
CONNECT localhost:80 HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

which yields the response headers

```
Content-Language   en
Content-Length   3612
Content-Type   text/html;charset=utf-8
Date   Thu, 21 Jun 2018 17:28:10 GMT
Mime-Version   1.0
Server   squid/3.5.27
Vary   Accept-Language
X-Squid-Error   ERR_DNS_FAIL 0
```

with status 503.
I also tried connecting to 127.0.0.1, which yields this response:

```
Content-Language   en
Content-Length   3433
Content-Type   text/html;charset=utf-8
Date   Thu, 21 Jun 2018 17:35:16 GMT
Mime-Version   1.0
Server   squid/3.5.27
Vary   Accept-Language
X-Squid-Error   ERR_CONNECT_FAIL 111
```

My squid.conf looks like this:

```
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl any_host src all
acl all_dst dst all

http_access allow any_host
http_access allow all_dst
```

Is there a different way to tell squid to connect to localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow squid tried to resolve `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, which ended up in a connection failure. Specifying `[::1]` instead of `localhost`, however, performs as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I found that what was failing what the `localhost` resolving to `[::1]` and not `127.0.0.1`.

In order to bypass the `/etc/hosts/` simply add the following to `/etc/squid/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Then `hosts_file /etc/squid/hosts` in your `squid.conf`.

Of course the file can be put anywhere you would like.

Comment: Looks like squid has some problem in name resolving. Although `nslookup` works fine with the proxy server's hostname, I have to add the line `<squid_proxy_server_ip_address> <squid_proxy_server_hostname>` into `/etc/squid/hosts`, and add `hosts_file /etc/squid/hosts` into `etc/squid/squid.conf` to overcome this `503`/`X-Squid-Error: ERR_DNS_FAIL` on the proxy server.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I need to add the line `<https_destination_server_ipaddr> <https_destination_server_hostname>` into `/etc/squid/hosts`, and add `hosts_file /etc/squid/hosts` into `etc/squid/squid.conf`. The mistake was made because my squid proxy and http/https service were running on the same machine.

Comment: You don't need to create a separate file. Check the default `/etc/hosts` file. You are probably missing the entry there. If you change the file you will lost all the definition in the default hosts file which might prevent other name resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using the squid machine hostname (e.g. **mysquid.proxy**) and the problem was not related to the DNS resolutions because the squid machine could resolve itself correctly using its hostname.

The problem was rather caused by the configuration of an additional port in the same proxy. I was using squid as both forward proxy and reverse proxy with two different ports:

- 3128 - forward proxy
- 443 - reverse proxy

The client was connecting to the (forward) proxy **mysquid.proxy:3128** and the request was something like:

```
CONNECT mysquid.proxy:443 HTTP/1.1
```

So the the reverse proxy port was used at the end.
However on that port it was configured a [url_rewrite_program](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/url_rewrite_program/) (a Perl script) to filter and change some path of specific url and such script was wrongly redirecting the request to a non-existant url which caused the error "**503 Service Unavailable**" in the client.